# If $p_1, p_2,...,p_s$ are distinct primes, show that an abelian group of order $p_1p_2\cdots p_s$ must be cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anyone give me some clues on this? Specific steps needed! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of finite(ly generated) abelian groups?

Comment: @IvoTerek: There are finite primes. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you know fundamental theorem of finite Abelian groups, you saved the work. If not, then

**Hint:** $\exists a,b$ such that $|a|=p_1, |b|=p_2$ **(why?)**, what is $|ab|=$? Can you use this fact to prove the claim? You just need to show that if $|a_i|=p_i$, then $|\prod a_i|=\prod p_i$

**Side note: The distinctness of primes is very important** (why?)